# Flyway migration error with DB2 11.1 SP including pure xml DDL

Tags: db2, flyway

I have a fairly complex Db2 V11.1 SP that will compile and deploy manually, but when i add the SQL to a migration script I get this issue

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2795

As the SP compiles and deploys manually, I am confident the SP SQL is ok.

Does anyone have any idea what the underlying issue might be

DB2 11.1
Flyway 6.4.1 (I have tried 7.x versions with same result)

the SP uses pure xml functions, so the SP SQL includes $ and @ characters
I tried using obscure statement terminator chars ( ~ ^) but a simple test with Pure xml functions and @ as statement terminator seemed to work

`--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET SCHEMA CORE
@
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CORE.XML_QUERY
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE OPTIONAL_ELEMENT (
LEG_SEG_ID BIGINT,
OPTIONAL_ELEMENT_NUM INTEGER,
OPTIONAL_ELEMENT_LIST VARCHAR(100),
CLSEQ INTEGER
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED WITH REPLACE;
insert into session.optional_element
select distinct LEG_SEG_ID, A.OPTIONAL_ELEMENT_NUM, A.OPTIONAL_ELEMENT_LIST, A.CLSEQ
from core.leg_seg , XMLTABLE('$d/LO/O' passing XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT(optional_element_xml)) as "d"
                             COLUMNS
                             OPTIONAL_ELEMENT_NUM INTEGER PATH '@Num',
                             OPTIONAL_ELEMENT_LIST VARCHAR(100) PATH 'text()',
                             CLSEQ INTEGER PATH '@Seq') AS A
WHERE  iv_id = 6497222690 and optional_element_xml is not null;
END

@`

Comment: please edit your question to show the ddl for the columns used in the sproc. It will also help if you show the symptom in plain text (not a link to an external website).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the responses
We have now forked flyway repo and fixed our issue. Will raise a PR back.